# Tibco EMS: How to specify prefetch settings for a dynamically-created queue?

Tags: c#, .net, tibco-ems

I'm using the EMS .NET client to send and receive messages from a queue. The queue is created dynamically, at runtime.

I need to override the default queue properties. Specifically, I need to disable prefetching. However, the default [prefetch](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-message-service-open-vms-c-client/8.2.0/doc/html/TIB_ems_api_reference/api/dotnetdoc/html/class_t_i_b_c_o_1_1_e_m_s_1_1_a_d_m_i_n_1_1_destination_info.html#a249b1387407e37c4959ff9a58c5e9ed7) count is set to 5 on the server, and this is the value which gets inherited.

Stepping through the code, I can see the queue is created during the `Session.CreateConsumer()` call, but I see no mechanism to specify any settings here.

Is it possible to create a dynamic queue with the prefetch behaviour disabled?

Comment: ActiveMQ seems to have something akin to what I need: [Destination Options](http://activemq.apache.org/destination-options.html)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143711/working-around-pre-fetch-in-tibco-ems-and-net-api